# How to dynamically change the height of the page header in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have a requirement that displaying different information on the page header of odd/even pages. So obviously both should be different height as per the text placement in the page header. We want to know that how to dynamically change the height of the page header.

As of now its taking constant height in page header through out all of the pages.

Comment: This sounds like something you should be handling in your presentation layer, e.g. PHP or Java, rather than in SQL Server.  Can you clarify what you are trying to do here?

Comment: This is possible in Crystal reports. SSRS just can't do that. Unless you came up with a customized solution like separate sub reports based header etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I have done the so many investigation that we couldnt control the height of the Report header/footer by dynamically as of sql server 2012 version. Height of the report header and footer is constant for all the pages.

Answer (score 0):

The height property of the header does not support expressions, but there is a workaround that may work for you.

You can show or hide text boxes based on an expression. 
Use `=iif(Globals!PageNumber Mod 2,True,False)` for the textboxes you want on the even pages. Use `=iif(Globals!PageNumber Mod 2,False,True)` for texboxes you want to see on the odd pages.

Comment: By using this expression I can able to hide the text boxes but I couldnt change the height of the page header dynamically.